# Erro em insert com ADOCommand

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe4, sql-server-2012

Em Delphi XE4, SQL Server 12, conectado por `ADOConnect`.

`ADOCommand1.commandText` sendo `'insert into tabela (a,b,c) (1,1,1)'`

Funciona como esperado, se já existir um registro. Mas se for o primeiro registro aparece a mensagem:

> "Uma linha vazia não pode ser inserida, a linha deve ter pelo menos um
>   valor de coluna definido"

Apesar da mensagem, o registro é incluído, verificado por uma query posterior.

Comment: Faltam detalhes mas creio que no segundo INSERT não estão passados valores para o objeto.

Comment: Acho que a sintaxe correta seria `INSERT INTO TABELA (a, b, c) **VALUES** (1, 1, 1)`, não?

Answer (score 1):

A Sintaxe esta incorreta

Seria assim

```
SQL.ADD('insert into tabela (a,b,c) VALUES (1,1,1)');
```

Answer (score -2):

Não falta a palavra reservada INTO?

insert into tabela (a,b,c) ***INTO*** (1,1,1)

Comment: a sintaxe correta é `INSERT **INTO** tabela (campo1, campo2) **VALUES** (valora, valorb) `